# How to calculate resultant of two polynomials without knowing the roots.

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

[image]

So in Rothstein - Trager's Method of evaluating logarithmic part they need resultant of two polynomial as shown in the image. My question is that how do they calculate the resultant without knowing the roots of these two polynomials? And if they know the roots then they can directly factorize the polynomials instead of going like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) is defined as the determinant of the [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix). Efficient computation is effected by the [sub-resultant algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Subresultant_pseudo-remainder_sequence).

Comment: Yeah I just found out :) 
@LutzL I wished to implement (rather complete the implementation) of Risch Algorithm for Symbolic Integration. Could you sugest me some references in that direction. My mathematical background extends to A first course in abstract algebra and graduate level course in universal algebra. But I have not studied differential fields so the common results I get on google seem to be quite heavy.

Comment: Another thing. In the image shown above, after calculating the resultant from the Sylvester Matrix, how do we factorize it symbolically ?

Comment: Zassenhaus + Hensel lifting, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_factorization#Factoring_univariate_polynomials_over_the_integers). But I have no further insight, also not for the Risch algorithm.